# git log -<number> does not work in Combination with LESS env Variable

Tags: linux, git, less

I want `git log` or `git diff` to clear the screen when I quit. I followed [this](https://superuser.com/a/367160/248359) instruction and added `export LESS="FR"` to my *.bashrc*, so that `git` does not add the `X` option to the less command (see [pager config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager)). It works as expected when I run `git log` or `git log -10`.

But as soon as I run `git log -6` (or something lower) nothing is outputted anymore. The reason seems to be the `quit-if-one-screen` mode. But I do not understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr

> I do not understand why this happens

`less` without `X` uses the alternate screen to display its output. If it quits immediately because of `F`, the alternate screen is displayed for very short time (if ever), effectively as if there was no output at all.

---

#### Relevant fragments of `man 1 less`

<sup>(in my Debian 9)</sup>

> `-F` or `--quit-if-one-screen`
>   Causes `less` to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

> `-X` or `--no-init`
>   Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

---

#### Preliminary notes

- The citation does not explicitly state that the behavior or "initialization and deinitialization strings" depend on `TERM` environment variable. In general it's good to assume any interaction beyond simple reading or echoing does depend on `TERM`. In case of `less` it does depend; e.g. with `TERM=vt100` you would most likely see no difference between the `X` option and the lack of it, and your request to "clear the screen when you quit" would *not* be solved by "not adding the `X` option to the `less` command".
- My tests were done with `TERM=screen`. I expect many other terminal types to behave similarly. I believe your issue is because your terminal behaves like mine and the rest of my answer applies.
- When trying the below commands verbatim, you should make sure your terminal is neither too small nor to large. My tests were done in a terminal with 30 lines.

---

#### Case 1: neither `F` nor `X`

When I do

```
seq 1 2 | LESS= less
```

or

```
seq 1 100 | LESS= less
```

neither `F` nor `X` is specified. The tool uses [alternate screen](https://superuser.com/a/321233/432690). This is from `man 1 xterm`:

> In VTxxx mode, there are escape sequences to activate and deactivate an alternate screen buffer, which is the same size as the display area of the window. When activated, the current screen is saved and replaced with the alternate screen. Saving of lines scrolled off the top of the window is disabled until the normal screen is restored.

I need to press <kbd>q</kbd> to make `less` leave the alternate screen and exit. The act of going back from the alternate screen to my normal screen is responsible for hiding the output of `less`. It's simple: the output exists in the alternate screen buffer but not in the normal screen buffer.

---

#### Case 2: `X` only

When I do

```
seq 1 2 | LESS=X less
# equivalent to
seq 1 2 | LESS= less -X
```

or

```
seq 1 100 | LESS=X less
# equivalent to
seq 1 100 | LESS= less -X
```

the tool does not send "initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal" that would normally switch buffers. All the output goes to the normal screen. Still I need to press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit.

---

#### Case 3: both options, `F` and `X`

When I do

```
seq 1 2 | LESS=FX less
# equivalent to
seq 1 2 | LESS= less -FX
```

or

```
seq 1 100 | LESS=FX less
# equivalent to
seq 1 100 | LESS= less -FX
```

the normal screen is used as well. If there are few enough lines, the tool will exit immediately *as if I hit <kbd>q</kbd> immediately* – this is how `F` works. After the tool exits its output is still visible because it's the normal screen I see all the time.

[The answer you linked to](https://superuser.com/a/367160/432690) states the default options used by Git are `FRSX`; [the config you linked to](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) reads `FRX` (it has changed after the answer had been published? or the answer was slightly wrong from the start). Anyway there is no doubt this is the case Git uses by default.

---

#### Case 4: `F` only

When I do

```
seq 1 2 | LESS=F less
# equivalent to
seq 1 2 | LESS= less -F
```

or

```
seq 1 100 | LESS=F less
# equivalent to
seq 1 100 | LESS= less -F
```

the alternate screen is used (like in the 1st case) but if there are few enough lines, `less` will exit immediately as if I hit <kbd>q</kbd> immediately (like in the 3rd case). In effect, if there are few enough lines, I won't see the output at all because the normal screen will be displayed right away. I won't notice the alternate screen; or maybe my terminal emulator or my video hardware won't even display it in the first place, I will see the normal screen on my monitor all the time. The output does not exist in the normal screen buffer. This is what you're experiencing.

---

#### Conclusion

You're right, `F` (or `quit-if-one-screen`) is crucial here. If you drop `X`, you should drop `F` as well. Note [the linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/367160/432690) does this: it goes from `FRSX` to `R` (`S` is responsible for line wrapping, irrelevant to the issue), i.e. it drops *both*. There's a comment that says "removing only `X` option is sufficient". My tests indicate the comment is wrong, it leads to the issue you experienced.